# How to convert my logo into white on a black background without distortion?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image: the thickness of the white cog on the black background is more than the black cog on white background]

My logo is colored, and the client asked me to make a white version of it. But unfortunately the logo’s thickness increases in this white version. How can I overcome this?

Comment: Simply changing the color should doesn't affect the shape. Perhaps there is a stroke doing something strange? Can you give more details about how you changed the color exactly?

Comment: I simply changed the color of the logo to white, but it seems to increase in size. No there is no stroke because the cog shape is expanded already .

Comment: I have checked your images, and the lines are exactly the same width in pixels (12 px). So, it would seem to be an optical illusion.

Comment: yes, It seems like that. Thanks @Billy because I put them on top of each other and they were exactly the same size.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an optical illusion. If all you have done is invert the colours, than that is all it is.

Answer (score 6):

It is a known optical effect that light lines on a dark background appear thicker than vice versa. [Here](https://fdi-type.de/faq/font-usage/what-are-the-positive-and-negative-styles-of-wayfinding-sans-pro-for-r2/) is a documentation of this effect for a font that comes in two variants to compensate for it.

You can account for it by making the light-on-dark strokes have approximately 0.92 the width of the dark-on-light strokes.
(The value is empirical and seems to match the proportions in said font.)